# \lstinputlisting won't allow me to change caption style (arabic instead of roman)

Tags: listings, captions

I am writing a document using a style that uses roman number for sections but for the rest arabics. For example, the document has Section I, Section II, but has Figure 5.3, Table 4.3.

I read the style file and know it is achieved by redefining `\def\thefigure {\@arabic\c@chapter.\@arabic\c@figure}`

However, the style file doesn't cover the `listing` case, so all my listing (of code) become something like this:

[image]

(which is not correct because the caption should be "Code 5.1")

Here is the latex to show my code:

```
\makeatletter
\lst@AddToHook{OnEmptyLine}{\vspace{-0.5\baselineskip}}
\makeatother
\lstinputlisting[
    float=tp,
    language=Matlab,
    caption = {\textbf{SonarMain.m.} The remote main script defines the sensing settings and creates a sensing server.}, 
    label = {\base:code:app_sonar_main},
    belowskip=-0.08in,
]{\base/codes/AppSonarMain.m}
```

After searching a similar issue, I notice a right solution might be:

```
\renewcommand{\thelstlisting}{\arabic{\thesection}-\arabic{lstlisting}}
```

However, nothing happens after I use this, is it because I am using `\lstinputlisting` instead of `begin{listing}`?

Comment: To mark your inline code, don't use double quotes but `\`` as I did in my edit.

Comment: This numbering seems odd. Are you forced to use it? If not, are you sure you want to use it?

Comment: Hi Skillmon, this is the thesis format (i.e., Sections in roman, but the rest in numbers) given by my university. So I have to use it.

Comment: Are you sure this is the case in `\mainmatter`, too? It is common to use `\Roman{chapter}` in the front matter and switch to arabic numbers in the main matter. Please verify this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is, that `listings` defines the counter and its formatting
`\AtBeginDocument`, so any changes have to be applied after that. The following
works.

```
\documentclass[]{report}

\usepackage{listings}

\makeatletter
\def\thechapter{\@Roman\c@chapter}% just in order to get Roman chapter number leave it out later
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \def\thelstlisting{\@arabic\c@chapter.\@arabic\c@lstlisting}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\chapter{Foo}
\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \rule{1cm}{3cm}
  \caption{foobar}
  \label{fig:foo}
\end{figure}
\begin{lstlisting}[caption=foobarCode]
for i in range(5):
    print("foo %i"%(i))
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Awesome solution! It works